# Comparing FormatPercent value in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, format, compare

I have a userform with 2 Textboxes and Label. Textboxes are meant for inserting decimal values. Label role is to show the result of 1st value divided by 1nd value(Textboxes).

I am trying to validate if inserted values are correct. If they are wrong Label.Caption will become red.

I have a code like this:

```
If Me.netto.Value = "" And Me.vat.Value = "" Or Me.vat.Value = "" Or Me.netto.Value = "" Then

Else
Procent_check.Caption = FormatPercent(CDbl(Me.vat) / CDbl(Me.netto), 2)

    If Procent_check.Caption >= 27 Or Procent_check.Caption <= 15 Then Else: Procent_check.ForeColor = vbRed

End If
```

When executed, it shows error at line `If Procent_check.Caption >=...` saying type mismatch.

No idea what type should I provide to check if value equals or higher than 27 or equals or smaller than 15...

Edit: 
Code for now, does not work color change...

```
If Me.netto.Value <> "" And Me.vat.Value <> "" _
And Me.vat.Value <> 0 And Me.netto.Value <> 0 Then

proc = CDbl(Me.vat) / CDbl(Me.netto)
MsgBox (proc)
MsgBox (Round(proc, 2))
Procent_check.Caption = FormatPercent(proc, 2)
    If Round(proc, 2) >= 0.27 Or Round(proc, 2) <= 0.15 Then
        Procent_check.ForeColor = vbBlack
    Else
        Procent_check.ForeColor = vbRed
    End If

End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormatPercent` returns *string* in format `"20%"` and you can't comare this string with numbers.

Try this one instead:

```
Dim res As Double
If Me.netto.Value <> "" And Me.vat.Value <> "" And Me.netto.Value <> 0 _
        And IsNumeric(Me.netto.Value) And IsNumeric(Me.vat.Value) Then
    res = CDbl(Me.vat) / CDbl(Me.netto)
    Procent_check.Caption = FormatPercent(res, 2)

    If res >= 0.27 Or res <= 0.15 Then
        Procent_check.ForeColor = vbBlack
    Else
        Procent_check.ForeColor = vbRed
    End If
Else
    Procent_check.Caption = ""
End If
```

Comment: Thanks it works! I don't need isnumeric, because textbox is validated for multiple cases with different code :)

Comment: glad it helps you:) You can remove `IsNumeric` part if you want, I've just added it for reliability:)

Comment: Yes, I did that. Just one thing makes me wonder. When I get 15% or 27% it turns red, when it should stay black. It does not happen when it's 15,01% or 26,9%...

Comment: it's formatting/rounding issue. E.g. if `res=0,26999999`, `FormatPercent(res, 2)` gives you `27%`. Try this one: `If Round(res, 2) >= 0.27 Or Round(res, 2) <= 0.15 Then`

Comment: It only made things worse... now it does not change color at all.

Comment: what is the values of `Me.vat` and `Me.netto`?

Comment: it works for me: it makes label red if `res` >15% AND <27%, i.g. for 20% label turns red, or you want reverse logic?

Comment: I am testing it for `me.netto = 100` and chaning `me.vat` from 14 to 28. No change of color. I'll edit my question to provide you actual code.

Comment: if `me.netto = 100` and `me.vat` from **16** to **26** it higlighted label in red for me with your code (for `me.vat` = 14 or 15 or 27 or 28 label is black) : http://i.stack.imgur.com/jJebv.png

Comment: if you want, here is test workbook: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l6l91g0lefp2sr6/test_form.xlsm . Enter in textboxes 100 for `netto` and 16 for `val`

Comment: 15 and 27 are numbers that should stay black.

Comment: @lowak, as I mentioned in comment above `for me.vat = 14 or 15 or 27 or 28 label is black`

Comment: ah... yeah so in this case thay should stay red. Range starts from 15 to 27. Not from 16 to 26.

Comment: can you explain for what precentage label should be black and for what should be red? change `If Round(res, 2) >= 0.27 Or Round(res, 2) <= 0.15 Then` to `If Round(res, 2) > 0.27 Or Round(res, 2) < 0.15 Then`

Comment: Whole problems is about one thing: with the given code I want to color label when it's numbers equals or higher than 15 or equals or lower than 27. It does not work for 15 and 27.

Comment: ...and now it's perfect :) Thank you.